# Get a series or dataframe indeces given a value in a column or in the series

Tags: pandas, indexing

I managed to solve my problem in two ways (sol1 and sol2), both seem to work ok. My question is more to understand how it works.

Sol2 first I filter the series, and what is left, I get the indices and then the list. I think I get it.

But sol1, first I get the indices, then put the filter to get only the values I want?

My Series is called serie.

print(serie.index[serie==serie.max()].tolist()) # sol 1

print(serie[serie==serie.max()].index.tolist()) # sol 2

Comment: You got it right. This is just boolean indexing. In one case after getting the index, in the other, before. In the first case you index the index, in the second the Series. Same mechanism, different objects.